# How to select a row using 2 columns

Tags: pandas

Within a DF I have 3 columns :
1 code - it is unique,
2 name - you can have 2 to 3 times the same name in this column,
3 value,

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
'code' : ['42305','42304','42306','B60LZR','BP3R22'],
'Long Name' : ['A.P. MOLLER-MAERSK' ,'A.P. MOLLER-MAERSK','A.P. MOLLER-MAERSK','AGRICULTURAL BK CH','AGRICULTURAL BK CH'],
'Value': [6.9,24.8,13.0,50.1,21.0]},
columns=['code','Long Name','Value'])
```

How do I eliminate the 'code' with the lowest 'value' for each 'Long Name' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each group has exactly one minimum, you can do:

```
df.drop(df.groupby('Long Name').Value.idxmin())
```

else:

```
df[df.Value != df.groupby('Long Name').Value.transform(min)]
```